# Issue with Multiple Nodes in XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to Add new keyword if  node with  "Name1" exist and if  node with "Name1" not exist and also if whole data node not exist then add whole predefine section as below:

```
<Data>
<Keyword>Keyword1</keyword>
<Name>Name1</Name>
<Data>
```

For Above I use below logic in XSL:

```
<xsl:param name="AddKeywords">
    <!-- Predefine Structure for Add Keyword -->
</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template
        match="data/[Name='Name1']/keyword[position()=last()]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$AddKeywords"/>`
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:param name="AddDataSection">
        <!-- Predefine Structure to Add Whole New Data Section -->
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:template
        match="data/[Name!='Name1'][position()=last()]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$AddDataSection"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Now problem is there are multiple Data Section in document, so if in First  section Name1 found then new keyword is add but also after that there are multiple Data node exist without Name1 data so it add keyword in first data section as well as also create whole new Data section, so duplication issue arrise. So Both Template is execute because of multiple data section.

So What is the Problem??

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. Currently I think you have more syntax errors like `"data/[Name='Name1']` or `data/[Name!='Name1']` than anything that is executable.

Comment: If Name=Name1 then execute first Template and if Name!=Name1 then execute second tempalte.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear what you are asking, but this might be what you are after.

- "If the `Data` element has a child `Name` element with text `Name1` then *append* some constant keywords to the existing `Keywords` child.
- "If the `Data` element does NOT have a child `Name` element with text `Name1` then remove all the contents of `Data` and replace this with default, populated `Keyword` and `Name` child elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:variable name="extraKeywords">,hello,world</xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="missingDataSection">
      <Keyword>SomeDefaultKeywords</Keyword>
      <Name>SomeDefaultName</Name>
   </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="Keyword[ancestor::Data[Name='Name1']]">
      <Keyword>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$extraKeywords"/>
      </Keyword>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Data[Name!='Name1']">
      <Data>
         <xsl:copy-of select="$missingDataSection"></xsl:copy-of>
      </Data>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this Xml:

```
<xml>
   <Data>
      <Keyword>Keyword1</Keyword>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <Keyword>AnotherKeyword</Keyword>
      <Name>NotName1</Name>
   </Data>
</xml>
```

Produces this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
   <Data>
      <Keyword>Keyword1,hello,world</Keyword>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
   </Data>
   <Data>
      <Keyword>SomeDefaultKeywords</Keyword>
      <Name>SomeDefaultName</Name>
   </Data>
</xml>
```

Comment: If you know that the `Keyword` always preceeds `Name` then I guess you could also replace the `Keyword[ancestor::Data[Name='Name1']]` with a `following-sibling`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my issue is if template one is execute then template 2 will not be execute, but using my code both template executes and duplication occur

Comment: Please can you provide a sample of the input xml, as well as the expected output xml. I am unclear on how many `Data` elements are per document.

Comment: If Name=Name1 then output is 

<xml>
   <Data>
      <Keyword>Keyword1</Keyword>
      <keyword>NewKeyword</keyword>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
   </Data>

</xml>

otherwise add whole new <Data> Section like:

<xml>
   <Data>
      <Keyword>NewKeyword1</Keyword>
      <Name>Name1</Name>
   </Data>
</xml>

Comment: Is it possible that if Template 1 is execute then template 2 should not be execute??